# Default Europe timezone set in php.ini, but date_default_timezone_get() returns 'UTC'

Tags: php, date, timezone

I've set in *php.ini* file the default timezone:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Rome
```

I've also restarted `httpd` service after the edit (service httpd restart), but when I call `date_default_timezone_get()`, it returns 'UTC' value.

Why this happens?

Also calling `php_info()` shows the timezone set in `php.ini`

PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Sometimes these will set the timezone. My guess is that it's being set in code. But without more details, I couldn't say where.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). No, it's not being set in the code. I used date_default_timezone_get() only to check if default timezone was set. Server time is set to the correct date (the current date here in Italy). If it can be useful, I have a dedicated server with CentoS 5.6.

Comment: It's being changed *somewhere*. I'd search your code for `date_default_timezone_set()`. You're not setting INI options via htaccess, vhost, etc?

Comment: No, I'm sure. And there's not that function in my code. Maybe I can try to upgrade PHP...

Comment: realizing this is a pretty big necro, i have this same issue. phpinfo() shows my proper timezone, but date_default_timezone_get() returns UTC. exact same issue. im on php 5.6.20

Answer (score 3):

If your code (including any frameworks) really does *not* change the timezone at all and you're running under a PHP version from 5.1.x to 5.3.x, it's possible, that the `TZ` environment variable is set somewhere in your system. Then your `date.timezone` setting would be *ignored*.

See the PHP manual page of [`date.timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) (emphasis mine):

> The default timezone used by all date/time functions. **Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this would only work if the TZ environment variable was not set**. […]

To check whether or not the `TZ` environment variable is set in your system, you could use

```
if (isset($_ENV['TZ'])) {
    echo 'TZ=' . $_ENV['TZ'];
}
else {
    echo 'TZ not set';
}
```

or put

```
phpinfo();
```

somewhere in your code and check the "PHP Variables" section at the very bottom of its output.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

In my `php.ini`, the **timezone** was well informed:
`date.timezone = Europe/Paris`

I checked with the php command `--ri date` 
and **timezone** in `php.ini` was well taken care of, so the error was not from the ini file.

The error came from the `httpd.conf` apache's file where is declared the variable **PHPIniDir**.

I had put `PHPIniDir "C:\PHP\"`

**You must remove the last back-slash which gives:** 
`PHPIniDir "C:\PHP"`

I hope this feedback will help.

(Just an precision, my environment is : Windows 7, php 5.4.32 and apache 2.2.25)