# date_default_timezone_get() returns different value than the default timezone set in php.ini

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have set the default timezone in php.ini as `date.timezone = "America/Bogota"`, and `phpinfo()` returns this value. But on runtime, `date_default_timezone_get()` returns `America/New_York`, which is not the value I have set. Also, `ini_get('date.timezone')` returns an empty value. I'm using PHP Version 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 with Apache 2.4.10.

This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869532/default-europe-timezone-set-in-php-ini-but-date-default-timezone-get-returns), but haven't been answered in 5 years.

Comment: What do you mean *on runtime* - like when your app runs? If so, then did you search your app to see if it sets the timezone?

Comment: I would say if you specifically want that timezone then you can manipulate it on ur code side as well, like by using settimezone() method provided by date class, if defining it in php.ini doesn't work

Comment: there are many approaches to handle a problem :)

Comment: Sure, I can set it using `date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota')`, but then I guess I'd have to set it in every php file that is using datetime objects, and I kinda want to avoid that (there are A LOT of files in the server U.U )

Answer (score 0):

I think if by defining on php.ini doesn't work for you, then you can handle it on your php code side during runtime by using something like this

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Bogota'));
```

Hope this helps!